# Find the roots of the given equation (complex numbers).

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

How can I find the roots of the given equation in $\mathbb{C}$?

$$z^4 + 4z^3 + 7z^2 + 6z + 3 = 0  $$

Comment: Hint : The factorizaion is $(z^2+z+1)\cdot (z^2+3z+3)$

Comment: @Peter It would be nice to show a technique to arrive at that factorization. The result can be had with a TI 89, but that barely gives any satisfaction...

Comment: Leg has given a nice possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(1,4,7,6,3)=(1,4,6,4,1)+(0,0,1,2,1)+(0,0,0,0,1)$,
$$ p(z)=z^4+4z^3+7z^2+6z+3 = (z+1)^4+(z+1)^2+1 $$
so in order to find the roots of $p(z)$ it is enough to find the roots of
$$ q(z) = z^4+z^2+1 = \color{red}{\frac{z^6-1}{z^2-1}} $$
that clearly lie on the unit circle.

Comment: Bravo! What amazing insight! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{align}
z^4+4z^3+7z^2+6z+3 & = (z^4+z^3+z^2) + (3z^3+3z^2+3z) + (3z^2+3z+3)\\
& = z^2(z^2+z+1) + 3z(z^2+z+1) + 3(z^2+z+1)\\
& = (z^2+3z+3)(z^2+z+1)
\end{align}